# Error in apache2 server for SSL certificate

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl-certificate

So I have purchased an SSL certificate, and need to add it to my Ubuntu running apache2 web service, however for some reason, my .conf file shows me the same error over and over again.

After running the code `apache2ctl configtest` they mentioned...

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 58 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/eblossom.conf:
Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

And in my .conf file...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        Alias /static /home/najaaz/eblossom/static
        <Directory /home/najaaz/eblossom/static>
          Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/najaaz/eblossom/media
        <Directory /home/najaaz/eblossom/media>
          Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/najaaz/eblossom/eblossom>
          <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
          </Files>
        </Directory>


        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/najaaz/eblossom/eblossom/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess eblossom python-path=/home/najaaz/eblossom python-home=/home/najaaz/eblossom/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup eblossom


                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    </VirtualHost>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<VirtualHost *:443>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /home/najaaz/eblossom/eblossom_lk.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/najaaz/eblossom/eblossom.lk.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /home/najaaz/eblossom/eblossom_lk.ca-bundle

</VirtualHost>
```

I a using a Django framework and I don't understand where and how this error is caused.
Could anyone help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: See my answer :)

Comment: </VirtualHost> is missing

Answer (score 0):

Run the following, and try again:

```
a2enmod ssl && systemctl restart apache2
```

Basically what this command does is that, it enables [mod_ssl](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html).

Comment: hey, it didn't seem to work at all. I have tried this before, did it one more time, still nothing

Comment: @Najaaz did you restart Apache?

Comment: But when I run `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -tls1` I am thrown with this..`error:141E70BF:SSL routines:tls_construct_client_hello:no protocols available:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1112:`

Comment: @Najaaz Your openssl version is. Probably messed up. I am sure.

Comment: @Najaaz try this command, `openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect 127.0.0.1:443`

Comment: Hey, as i ran this command as u sd I was thrown with this error,  `:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:331:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 188 bytes
Verification: OK`.... Seems like there is a wrong version number lolz